# What is the ibm bluemix blockchain port for events?

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

The Hyperledger peers in version 0.6 use port 7053 for events. But I cant find any bluemix documentation that tell me which port I can use to connect to a bluemix blockchain peer to consume events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the "Service Credentials" tab and then look for the "View Credentials" link, you'll find the hostname and ports (GRPC, REST, Event) for each peer

[image]